# DateTime formatting on Kendo Grid foreign key column

Tags: datetime, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo grid that has a foreign key column as follows...

```
.Columns(col =>
{
   col.ForeignKey(c => c.ScheduleID, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewBag.schedules, "ID", "EventDate").Title("Date");
})
```

Currently, the column is displayed as a DateTime like '01/18/2016 12:00:00:00 AM' and I would like to have it as '01/18/2016'. I know on a 'Bound' column, you can use the .ClientTemplate to format the date time field, but how can I do this same thing on a foreign key column?

Answer (score 0):

```
.Columns(col =>
{
   col.ForeignKey(c => c.ScheduleID, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewBag.schedules, "ID", "EventDate").Title("Date").Format("{0:M/d/yyyy}");
})
```

Comment: I tried that already, and it is not working for me. Any other suggestions?

Comment: May I see the method used in the grid?